# SevenZipSharp on Mono / Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm working in a C# application which processes various types of archive files by shelling out to 7zip. As you can imagine, this is horribly buggy and non-performant.

I would dearly love to replace this with the SevenZipSharp library (http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/), but I cannot for the life of me get it to work under Mono on Linux. Has anybody managed to do this? What are the steps for getting it to work?

I presume that the actual 7zip Windows DLL is going to be completely useless on Linux. I tried using the `7z.so` file that comes with `p7zip`, but SevenZipSharp whines that "the entry point does not exist".

I also tried getting the source code. There's a hopeful looking `SevenZipMono` subproject, but it doesn't build due to several source code files not existing. (`COM.cs`, `MonoSpec.cs`, `InterfaceWrapper.cs`, etc.) It looks as if the files literally haven't been committed for some reason. At this point, I'm totally stuck.

(I also found a fork of SevenZipSharp on GitHub, but it appears to be identical to the main project. It too doesn't build for exactly the same reason.)

Any suggestions on how to make this stuff actually work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the project, but after looking at the source, it looks like a Windows-specific project to me, due to the interop with kernel32 and COM. I would guess that even the Mono implementation is designed to work on Mono under Windows and not Linux.

Comment: .Net 4.5 has much-improved zip support built in compared to prior versions. Look in System.IO.Compression. Is that an option?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'm not just interested in one format. I want something that will handle 7z, PK-zip, GZip, BZip2, tar, rar, zoo, compress, etc. It's not hard to find an individual library for each of those, but there aren't too many that handle _all_ of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far you have two options,

1. Fix SevenZipSharp on Mono/Linux to PInvoke 7z.so. That requires you to change the PInvoke definition in source code, and also recompile the source files. If even the developers of that project did not yet make it right, I think you will need to pay much attention to that approach.
2. Switch to a full managed implementation, such as

https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress

Comment: Option #2 only appears to cover 7z files. I want to handle _every_ type of archive. That's why I didn't just opt to using the LZMA SDK which 7zip already offers; it only covers 7z.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, I just edited my answer as there is a better library that supports most common formats.

Comment: SharpCompress hasn't been maintained in a while. My first attempts to use it resulted in failure first identify a 7z file, and then read it.  It's a pity there isn't better support for 7Zip on C#

Comment: Its last commit at GitHub was on July 1, 2014. I don't think that's "hasn't been maintained in a while". About the failure you met, would you mind opening an issue and consult the developer?

Comment: Now, SharpCompress is not implemented LZMA2 compression, and it's PPMd decompression is very slow. It's homepage found a MONO version https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZipMono/ but i still not tested it.